# Unable to install gym-retro: subprocess.CalledProcessError for cmake

Tags: python-3.x, cmake, openai-gym

It's another pip installation error (those drive me crazy). I am on Windows 8.1 with python 3.7. I was attempting to install gym-retro through pip (I already have gym installed) and kept encountering a subprocess error. I figured it was because I did not have cmake or something, so I went on the cmake website and installed cmake, and checked the "add to PATH" option. After that I attempted to install it again. Same issue. I restarted my command prompt as well. I tried to find help online, but nothing seemed to help. I resigned to running the command

```
pip install gym-retro > output.txt
```

to gather the output and post it here. I stripped it down so it would not be painful to look at.

```
Building wheels for collected packages: gym-retro
  Building wheel for gym-retro (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for gym-retro (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Complete output from command c:\users\evgeny\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Evgeny\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-t3ctdvi3\\gym-retro\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\Evgeny\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-q1w5imfc --python-tag cp37:
  use_scm_version False
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win32-3.7
  creating build\lib.win32-3.7\retro
  copying retro\enums.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\retro
  copying retro\retro_env.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\retro
  copying retro\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\retro
  creating build\lib.win32-3.7\retro\data
  copying retro\data\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\retro\data
  creating build\lib.win32-3.7\retro\data\stable
  copying retro\data\stable\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\retro\data\stable

</skipped lots of text here/>

    running build_ext
    -- Submodules seem to be missing. Attempting to clone now.
    CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:13 (message):
      Failed to check out submodules.  Aborting.


    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Evgeny\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-t3ctdvi3\gym-retro\setup.py", line 92, in <module>
        **kwargs
      File "c:\users\evgeny\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 131, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "c:\users\evgeny\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "c:\users\evgeny\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "c:\users\evgeny\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\evgeny\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "c:\users\evgeny\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "c:\users\evgeny\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\evgeny\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\evgeny\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "c:\users\evgeny\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\evgeny\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\Evgeny\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-t3ctdvi3\gym-retro\setup.py", line 53, in run
        subprocess.check_call([cmake_exe, '.', '-G', 'Unix Makefiles', build_type, pyext_suffix, pylib_dir, python_executable])
      File "c:\users\evgeny\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 341, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['C:\\Users\\Evgeny\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\Scripts\\cmake.exe', '.', '-G', 'Unix Makefiles', '', '-DPYEXT_SUFFIX:STRING=.cp37-win32.pyd', '-DPYLIB_DIRECTORY:PATH=build\\lib.win32-3.7', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE:STRING=c:\\users\\evgeny\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37-32\\python.exe']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I found was to install Ubuntu on a virtual machine and install it there (for anyone who has this problem in the future).

Comment: similar problem but on linux. I think now that installing it via conda is less problematic and should work on "any" platform [haven't test it]. For windows is suggested to use docker container, [doc](https://retro.readthedocs.io/en/latest/developing.html#windows)